# String Date to ISODate in Mongo with extra quotes

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date

I have this not very smart formatted Date:

```
"@timestamp" : "\"2017-06-02T06:59:57.205Z\""
```

I want to turn it into a ISODate properly but no success because of the `"` and `\` I guess.

```
db.test.find().forEach(function(d) { d['@timestamp'] = ISODate((d['@timestamp']).replace(/\"|\\/g, "")); db.collection.save(d); })

db.test.find().forEach(function(d) { d['@timestamp'] = ISODate(JSON.parse(d['@timestamp'])); db.collection.save(d); })

db.test.find().forEach(function(d) { d['@timestamp'] = ISODate(d['@timestamp']); db.collection.save(d); })
```

What is the easiest approach?

Comment: Using JSON parse is my favoured approach.

Comment: `new Date(d['@timestamp'].replace(/\"|\\/g, ""))`. You `.replace()` on the "string" and not the `Date()` part. This is not your day.

Comment: @evolutionxbox Why? It does not work? Why would your favorite be the one that fails?

Comment: Are you sure it fails? http://jsbin.com/gufopuhare/edit?js,console

Comment: @evolutionxbox That's what the OP is saying. Their first approach was closest, but they had a typo.

Comment: Haha Neil :-D I have an extra parentheses there: `(d['@timestamp']).replace(/\"|\\/g, "")`

Comment: I think you need a coffee or a walk around. Also look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field/37280419?noredirect=1#comment76460616_37280419 And use `.bulkUpdate()` here rather than `.save()` in these loops.

Comment: @evolutionxbox the @timestamp field afterwards is still `"@timestamp" : "\"2017-06-02T06:59:57.205Z\"",`

Comment: oh lol! I am reading from collection `test` but writing to collection `collection`....